# UIImageViewController has no status after taking photo in preview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I use following code to take picture

```
self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
self.imagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

after taking, it will jump to a preview with two button: `retake` and `use`

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

the above class method can't be called until i click the button `use`,  so is there any class method can I use when entering preview view? thanks

Comment: I guess there is no :(

Comment: @Retro thanks, another question, if i set OverlayView, and use `[self.imagePickerController takePicture];` to take picture, and is there any way to enter the preview view?

Comment: you have to handle that kinda functionality by your own as when delegate called didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo you can show your own preview view and add there that kinda thing for choose or retake

Comment: @Retro ok, I thought there's a way to go to the original preview view, but in fact, there's no if use my own overlayer, thanks.